# Any advice for iPhone Wireless Comms with Embedded Linux Device?

Tags: iphone, rest, soap, embedded-linux, dlna

I am looking for advice on protocols for use in LAN comms between an iPhone and an embedded Linux device. The embedded Linux device requires the following functionality...

1. Connectible to Wireless LAN.
2. Discoverable as a device on the Wireless LAN.
3. (Virtually) connectible with iPhone.
4. Remotely Callable API provided to the iPhone.
5. Able to remotely call back functions on the iPhone.

I am looking to use platform independent protocols to achieve this functionality because the mobile application will be ported from the iPhone to other mobile platforms like Android. Since I am a  newbie with Embedded Linux, my research (and possibly naivety) suggests that said functionality could be realised with the following protocols...

1. DHCP for obtaining dynamic IP address.
2. DNLA? (Bonjour is native to iOS right?)
3. Connection-oriented communication implies TCP.
4. SOAP or REST architecture on HTTP.
5. SOAP or REST architecture on HTTP.

Can you suggest other, more suitable protocols? Am I barking up the wrong tree? Is there a much more simple way I could achieve this functionality? For example, providing the remote API using only a TCP socket?

Any advice you can offer is welcome...

Comment: DLNA is about specific audio/video APIs so that's probably not applicable: However, SSDP may be an option for device/service discovery, but so is Avahi (which is the bonjour equivalent on linux: both implement zeroconf). UPnP may be useful for the method/property definitions -- in this case SSDP is a given as UPnP defines that as the discovery method.

Comment: I did try UPnP because of it's auto discovery, RPC over HTTP, and an event notification mechanism. OhNet is an open UPnP stack that's well supported and can be built for both Linux and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [0mq](http://www.zeromq.org/). It's a scalable messaging library that provides a message queue without requiring a message broker.

-Has objective-c bindings to help you implement in iOS
-Has java bindings to help you implement in Android.
-Small footprint.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar - an Arduino that streams data to an iPhone app connected over WiFi using the UDP protocol.

Comment: What protocol did you use for device discovery?

Comment: I just used UDP broadcast. Basically any device on the network can listen.